# Read a remote equivalentClass of ontology in Jena

Tags: jena, owl, dbpedia

When I run "getEquivalentClass()" and my equivalentClass is remote (EX: http://dbpedia.org/data3/Film.rdf) raise error:

Cannot convert node http://dbpedia.org/data3/Film.rdf to OntClass: it does not have rdf:type owl:Class or equivalent

My code is:

```
OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    m.read("http://localhost/ontology/my_ontology.owl#Film");
    Resource r = m.getResource(outputs.get(i).getParamType().getURI().toString());
    OntClass filmClass = (OntClass) r.as( OntClass.class );
    for (Iterator j = filmClass.listEquivalentClasses(); j.hasNext(); ) {
        System.out.println(j.next());
    }
```

Film Ontology (my_ontology.owl#Film):

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="#Film">
<rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Media"/>
<rdfs:subClassOf>
<owl:Restriction>
<owl:minCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minCardinality>
<owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#Title"/>
</owl:Restriction>
</rdfs:subClassOf>
<owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/data3/Film.rdf"/>
</owl:Class>
```

It's is possible? I lost many hours finding this solution.

Thanks for help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer of **Dave Reynolds** of Jena users list:

It's not to do with whether the resource is remote but whether the local model knows that the resource really is a class.

The easiest solution is to just set:

```
m.setStrictMode(false);
```

An alternative is to enable inference so the inference can deduce from the fact that it is the object of an owl:equivalentClass assertion that http://dbpedia.org/data3/Film.rdf must be a class. But inference is overkill here.

BTW that's the wrong URI, the dbpedia resource URI for film is actually:

```
  http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film
```